# list append not working (list always empty)

Tags: python, list

I'm making a game and I created a loop in a class that creates a list with every sprite I need from my sprite sheet.

The problem is that when I try to blit an element of the list, I always get this error: IndexError: `list index out of range`

Here's the code of the function in the class (simplified):

```
    def sprites(self):
        i = 1
        boxwidth = 0
        boxwidthend = False
        sprites = []
        
        for i in range(1,0,5):
            while i <= 2:
                boxheight = 0
                spritesurface = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.heightside), pygame.SRCALPHA)
                spritesurface.blit(self.type, (0,0), (0 + boxwidth, 0, self.width, self.heightside))
                sprite = pygame.transform.scale(spritesurface, (self.width * self.scale, self.heightside * self.scale))
                sprites.append(sprite)

            while i <= 5:
                boxheight = 49
                if boxwidthend == False:
                    boxwidth = 0
                    boxwidthend = True
                spritesurface = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.heightup), pygame.SRCALPHA)
                spritesurface.blit(self.type, (0,0), (0 + boxwidth, boxheight, self.width, self.heightup))
                sprite = pygame.transform.scale(spritesurface, (self.width * self.scale, self.heightup * self.scale))
                sprites.append(sprite)
            boxwidth += 25
            i += 1

      return sprites
```

and here's the main code section (simplified):

```
sprites_class = GetSprites("human", 3)
spritelist = sprites_class.sprites()
while True:
   ROOT.blit(spritelist[3], (playermovement.x, playermovement.y))
```

Comment: range(1,0,5) how this can run ??

Comment: This is in infinite loop: `while i <= 2:` since you never increment `i` inside the loop. I suspect you mean `if i <= 2:`

Comment: @Barmar I think it will never go inside the loop because for condition will not allow this

Comment: @DeepakTripathi Right, but if she fixed the range she'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: The function has no `return` statement. So you won't assign anything to `spritelist`.

Comment: @Barmar That may be the reason she don't want to go inside loop  hahahahaha

Comment: Or 2 separate loops: `for i in range(0, 3):` then `for i in range(3, 6):`

Comment: @DeepakTripathi 1 is the step, 0 is the start and 5 is the end, Id solved by incrementing i, i forgot to put the return here but it was in the code

Comment: @AndreaRoncella Your explanation is wrong. In `range(1,0,5)` the `1` is the start, the `0` is the last value (not included) and `5` is the step. Look at the documentation of [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Comment: @AndreaRoncella no, `1` is the start, `0` is the end, and `5` is the step, `range(1,0,5)` is an empty range, try it out with `print(list(range(1,0,5)))`

Comment: Which means you simply want `range(6)` to get the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  That's it..  And, if course, the `while` statements should be `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments:

1. Range takes three parameters

   - start Optional. An integer number specifying at which position to start. Default is 0
   - stop  Required. An integer number specifying at which position to stop (not included).
   - step  Optional. An integer number specifying the incrementation. Default is 1

   So if you want to loop numbers `1` through `5`, all you need is `Range(6)` as the optional `start` parameter defaults to `0` and the optional `step` parameter defaults to `1`.
2. `while i<=2:` will result in an infinite loop as there is no way for the value of `i` to change inside the loop. Once you enter it, it will go on forever. Instead you want an `if` and `elif`

---

```
def sprites(self):
    
    boxwidth = 0
    boxwidthend = False
    sprites = []
    
    for i in range(6):
        if i <= 2:
            print("i <= 2")
            boxwidth += 1
            boxheight = 0
            spritesurface = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.heightside), pygame.SRCALPHA)
            spritesurface.blit(self.type, (0,0), (0 + 25 * boxwidth, 0, self.width, self.heightside))
            sprite = pygame.transform.scale(spritesurface, (self.width * self.scale, self.heightup * self.scale))
            sprites.append(sprite)

        elif i <= 5:
            print("i > 2")
            boxheight = 48
            if boxwidthend == False:
                boxwidth = 0
                boxwidthend = True
            spritesurface = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.heightup), pygame.SRCALPHA)
            spritesurface.blit(self.type, (0,0), (0 + 25 * boxwidth, boxheight, self.width, self.heightup))
            sprite = pygame.transform.scale(spritesurface, (self.width * self.scale, self.heightup * self.scale))
            sprites.append(sprite)
    return sprites
```

Comment: @OP you submitted an edit wherein you suggested incrementing `i` as the last step inside of the for loop. Please understand that `i` is already being incremented as a part of the `for` loop. If you increment within the loop also, then you will only look at every-other-`i`. It would be functionally equivalent to `for i in range(0,6,2):`. Furthermore you suggested `i=0` at the top of the function. This is superfluous. `i` is defined in the `for` loop. It doesn't need to be defined twice.